# How to add fixed placeholder text to an input box and prevent the user from deleting it on a web page?

Tags: html, css

Working on an ordering table for a new product and one of the columns is to specify the RAL color of the product.

I want to have fixed text that the user can't delete so all they have to do is enter a four digit number after that which relates to the RAL colour.

The problem I'm having is the input is going over the fixed text and not after it - see below.

[image: input over fixed text]

Please ignore the design of the table as I'm working on the functionaility for now and its looking a bit rubbish.

HTML:

```
<td class="lst-input-ral-box">
     <input value="" id="ral" maxlength="4" autofocus="autofocus">
     <span class="ral-placeholder">RAL</span>
 </td>
```

CSS:

```
.lst-input-ral-box {
   position: relative; 
}
.input {
    display: block; 
    border: 1px solid #d7d6d6; 
    background: #fff;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 20px;
    width: 195px;
}
.ral-placeholder {
    position: absolute; 
    display: block;
    left: 5px; 
    top: 3px; 
    z-index: 9;  
}
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated as I'm fairly new to 'complex' coding.

Comment: fyi: `.input` isn't used in the code you posted

Comment: Why not just put the "RAL" text to the left of the box? No fuss: https://jsfiddle.net/stgLe42z/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if I have well understood, you want to add 4 digits after the "RAL" constant right ?

Is so, you should replace

```html
<input value="" id="ral" maxlength="4" autofocus="autofocus">
<span class="ral-placeholder">RAL</span>
```

with:

```html
<label for="ral" class="ral-placeholder">RAL</label>
<input type="text" value="" id="ral" name="ral" maxlength="4" autofocus="autofocus">
```

PS : you have to know that the `name` attribute is a good practice to use correctly in the `for=""` from `<label>` tag, even if `id` is working also.

Comment: Not sure if I understood your PS correctly, but the `for` attribute _only_ links to an `id` attribute, not a `name` attribute

Comment: This and the comment above worked brilliantly. Decided to go with your idea and solution to put RAL text to the left of the box. Thank you for taking the time to help on this, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 4):

Don't put the static text *inside* the input, put it *before* the input.  You can style it to "appear" to be inside the input by removing the border/outline/etc. from the input and adding it to the containing element.  For example:

```css
.lst-input-ral-box {
  border: 1px solid #d7d6d6;
}
.lst-input-ral-box:focus-within {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
input {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="lst-input-ral-box">
     <span class="ral-placeholder">RAL</span>
     <input value="" id="ral" maxlength="4" autofocus="autofocus">
   </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Edit:** For completeness, this can be further improved by changing the `<span>` to a `<label>`, which will focus the `<input>` when activated.  I've also reduced the "gap" between the two contained elements, so the full clickable area *should* activate the `<input>`:

```css
.lst-input-ral-box {
  border: 1px solid #d7d6d6;
  display: flex;
  gap: 0;
}
.lst-input-ral-box:focus-within {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
input {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="lst-input-ral-box">
     <label for="ral" class="ral-placeholder">RAL</label>
     <input value="" id="ral" maxlength="4" autofocus="autofocus">
   </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Note that a `<label>` for an `<input>` has an important semantic meaning.  One should take accessibility into consideration here, as not all users will visually observe or care about this stylistic placement.

Does this element "label" the input?  Semantically that's for you to decide.  Combinations of `aria-` attributes and other functionality can also be used to achieve reasonable designs while keeping the markup semantically clear.

Comment: An extra bonus would be to add a click handler to the container to focus the input box. Or using a label element as unshiny99 has done.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to provide a solution, I really appreciate it.